# xcode - change design of all graphics component

Tags: xcode, graphics

There is a way to change the graphics of a component type (such as all buttons) in the storyboard without changing it one by one?

I have to change the look of all components using a design purchased.
My views in storyboard, however, are many and I would put too much to change them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

In the left of your screen in xcode there is a list of all view controllers, you can expand all of them and press command + select the control that you want , then you can make some of change.

so these changes affect to all controls.

I think this is the only way.